# Chrome Extension Message Passing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, coffeescript

I have a chrome extension that's sending a login message:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage data, (response) ->
  debugger
  if response.api_key
    $("body").fadeOut 1000, -> window.close()

  else
    App.Ui.clearForm()
    App.Ui.showErrorMessage()
```

However, the callback is never hit:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener (request, sender, sendResponse) ->
  if request and request.action is "login"

    $.ajax(
      type: "POST"
      url: App.Config.authUrl()
      data: request.data
      dataType: "json"
    ).then( (data) ->

      App.Storage.saveSession(data.user)
      sendResponse(data.user)

    , (data) ->

      sendResponse(data)

    )
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [documentation for `onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) about `sendResponse`:

> This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called).

So, to fix your code, you need to return `true` in the listener after your async call.